# Deep Learning Model that predicts optimal ElasticSearch Query-time Boost Values

Tags: elasticsearch, tensorflow

I would like to use a machine learning model to train the optimal boost values to use when calling [ElasticSearch Query-time Boosting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html).

The ElasticSearch documentation recommends a trial-and-error approach:

> Apply a boost and check the results. Change the boost and check again.

I would like to be more calculated in what these values should be and leverage machine learning with randomized input values to predict the optimal boost values for given search terms. I looked at [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/using-machine-deep-learning-for-guessing-pseudo-random-generator) as potentially similar to the problem I am trying to solve, but wanted to make sure I am heading in the right direction before getting too far along.

Comment: Interesting, what do you plan to use to set the boosting scale? Number of terms in query?

Comment: @sramalingam24, the query can have between 2 - 10 terms (all exact match). I consider the boosting scale relative to what range of random numbers I use. Is that the right way to look at this?